# Git branch management vs deployable environments

Tags: git, gitflow

I am looking for a git branch management model that would be used easily and would allow for Continuous Integration/Delivery.

Imagine I have 3 environments: `prod`, `uat` and `dev`.

The code repository includes source code as well as infrastructure as code files (in this case `serverless.yml`)

I would like to use semantic versioning for the source code (git tags?) and I want to have auto deploys on releasing a new version.

The way I currently picture it is that there are only 2 locked branches in git: `master` and `dev`. Where `master` matches the current `prod` environment (every time I merge to master it is deployed to `prod`). Every commit pushed to `dev` is deployed to `dev` environment and every tag pushed to `dev` is deployed to `uat`.

All of this seems kind of possible, but there are some things unclear to me:

- *How do I manage changes to the infrastructure that "doesn't affect the source code"? Let's say I need to increase the number of deployed instances etc.*
- *Ideally, I would only like uat-accepted versions to be released to production, how could I make sure that no untagged commits will make it to the `prod` environment?*

I am looking for recommendations on how to approach this topic in general. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very generic, and so generic answers are inevitable. That said, I figured I can share with you (at a high level) how we do our gitflow/devops at our company. You can go ahead and take a look, and then ask more specific questions.

This is our [gitflow](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1xbRTqsO3nHMHHoS0yDxOAljrwrbs5LZ8kQzkyP-Kf0I/edit). We use [AWS cloud deploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/) to automate the deployment of code when pushing to various git branches using [bitbucket pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines).  You can see a sneak peak of how we tie that up [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4675/how-to-optimize-blue-green-aws-deployments/).